# The intuition of the rank theorem

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-topology

In Rudin's Principle of Math Analysis, I know the proof of the rank theorem. However, I fail to understand its content.

9.32 Theorem: Suppose $m,n,$ are nonnegative integers, $m\geq r,n\geq r$, $F$ is a $C^1$ mapping of an open set $E\subset R^n$ into $R^m$, and $F'(x)$ has rank $r$ for every $x\in E$.

Fix $a\in E$, put $A=F'(a)$, Let $Y_1$ be the range of A, and let $P$ be the projection in $R^m$ whose range if $Y_1$. Let $Y_2$ be the null space of $P$.

Then there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $R^n$, with $a\in U,U\subset E$ and there is a 1-1 mapping $H$ of $V$ onto $U$(whose inverse is also of class $C^1$) such that

(66) $F(H(x))=Ax+\phi(Ax)$ $(x\in V)$ where $\phi$ is a $C^1$ mapping of open set $A(V)\subset Y_1$ into $Y_2$.

It is clear that F is a manifold of dimension r. However, what is the purpose of H? I do not understand the content of H. Or should I treat H as a chart of the manifold described by F?

Comment: You can see [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669881/question-about-statement-of-rank-theorem-in-rudin?rq=1)